# PreparedStatement causing OOM errors

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, prepared-statement

I have a listener method that contains the following code. That method is called multiple times a second. It is, however, causing a memory leak within my application.

I think it may be with the way I am handling the prepared statement (creating new one for each object received).  Am I doing anything obviously wrong? Should I be setting the PS to null once it's used? Are the PSs being retained for some reason?

Also, I'm manually specifying the table name for the PS. Is that redefinition defeating the purpose of using a Prepared Statement entirely?

```
String text = object.getText();

//determineDb method determines the db for the object based on its content
ArrayList<Topic> toAddList = determineDatabase(text);
if (toAddList.size() > 0) {
    int epoch = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    //Topic class contains DB info, topic name and associated terms
    for (Topic a : toAddList) {
        try {
            pst = con
    .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "
            + a.getTopic()
            + " (created, received, username, text, ignored, retweet, value) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(object.getCreatedAt().getTime() / 1000));
            pst.setString(2, String.valueOf(epoch));
            pst.setString(3, object.getUser());
            pst.setString(4, text);
            pst.setInt(5, 0);
            pst.setInt(6, object.isOriginal() ? 1 : 0);
            pst.setDouble(7, otherClass.analyzeString(object.getText()));
            pst.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to find the source of the leak, you should take periodic heap dumps of the JVM an analyze them.  This will allow you to see what kinds of objects are accumulating on the heap and, hopefully, make the cause of the leak obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *must* close your PreparedStatement after you use it, always in a finally block.  Any object in java which could correspond to an external resource should *always* be handled carefully (cleaned up as soon as it is no longer useful).  All JDBC resources fall into this category (ResultSet,Statement,Connection).

Comment: Thank you. Any way to test this without having to wait the day or so it usually takes for the error to throw? Will lowering the amount of heap space be beneficial?

Comment: @Peter - you can use a tool like jvisualvm (comes with the jdk) or any other free memory profiler to monitor the jvm memory and see if it is holding steady or increasing.  lowering heap memory will help as well.

Comment: @Peter - using the "heap dump on out of mem" flag you mentioned below is also advisable as that will allow you to examine the heap after the app crashes (which may happen when you aren't monitoring it).

Comment: you should move the PreparedStatement creation outside of the loop for better efficiency though.

Comment: @MartinSerrano : I guess, he is doing that because table name is not fixed so eventually query is not fixed . `"INSERT INTO " + a.getTopic()`